# how to write the following equations

Tags: math-mode, cases

I am currently working on including the following equation in my writing:

[image: Equation Image]

I attempted to express it as follows, but my attempt produced a very different result

```
$y = f(x) = \{\dfrac{-\dfrac{\pi}{4} (-\pi \le x \leq   0)}
                    { \dfrac{\pi}{4} (   0 \le x \leq \pi)}$
```

Could someone kindly help me accurately represent the intended equation in LaTeX?